# vb.net windows form

Tags: vb.net

How could i validate a textbox in vb.net, so that it gives error message if i enter anything  like , or .

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event handler for the TextBox's `Validating` event to check for invalid characters.

If there is an invalid character, you can set the `Cancel` property of the Validating event's `e` parameter to `True`.

Check this out for more information: [Control.Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt validation controls available Windows Forms.